# Pass a pointer as array in function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void f(int *a, int n)
{
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         printf("%d\n", *(a+i));
     }
 }
```

The above code worked ok if in `main()` I called:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *p = a;

f(a, 3);
```

But if in `main()`, I did:

```
int *a =(int*) {1,2,3};

f(a, 3);
```

Then, the program will crash. I know this might look weird but I am studying and want to know the differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of the cast. This line says:

```
int *a =(int*) {1,2,3};
```

Treat the array `{1,2,3}` as a pointer to an int. On a 32 bit machine, the value of the pointer is now `1`, which is not what you want.

However, when you do:

```
int *p = a;
```

The compiler knows that it can decay the array name to a pointer to it's first element. It's like you'd actually written:

```
int *p = &(a[0]);
```

Similarly, you can just pass `a` straight in to the function, as the compiler will also decay the array name to a pointer when used as a function argument:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *p = &(a[0]);

f(p, 3) 
f(a, 3); // these two are equivalent
```

Comment: Also note that you can assign `a` by using the following: `int *a = (int *) (int []) { 1, 2, 3 };`